# Retrieve the latest data in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy

I have 3/4 columns with revision numbers (P01, P02, P03 etc.), I would like to construct a formula that shows me the latest revision number in a new column so that i don't need to scroll to the far right of the sheet to obtain this info.

Additionally, when i highlight a column, it ends up highlighting the following 3 columns next to it. Why is this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser, please edit your question and add a screenshot of a sample how your sheets looks and where on the sheet you'd want that "latest revision number" to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses your first question:

Assuming you have an id in column `A`, want to construct your formula in column `B`, and have your data stored in e.g., the range `C1:E5`; exemplary data and result:

| id | revision | P01 | P02 | P03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P02 | x | x |  |
| 2 | P02 |  | x |  |
| 3 | P01 | x |  |  |
| 4 | P03 | x |  | x |
| 5 | P03 |  |  | x |

In that case, you could, for example, combine `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` as follows for the first row below headers (i.e., cell `B2` and drag it down):

```
=INDEX($C$1:$E$1, 1, MATCH("x", C2:E2, 1))
```

This formula takes as the array the headers of the revisions (which you ultimately want to return). Given that you construct the formula in every row, it always uses the first row and the column should be return based on the last match of "x" across the revisions.

This approach will, however, only work if you have in your cells an "x" respectively.

**A more general approach** could look as follows:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$E$1, 1, MAX(IF(C2:E2<>"", COLUMN(C2:E2)-COLUMN(C2)+1, 0)))
```

This approach is not based on the fact that there is an "x" in a respective cell but rather looks for the last non-empty cell in the respective range, e.g., `C2:E2`. Thus, you want to identify the last column that has a non-empty cell and correct it by the number of columns that the data is offset by the column id and revision, given that they are not counting. Based on this you return the respective header.

PS: Answering the second question is impossible without further details (e.g., screenshots etc.)

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, if your excel sheet looks like this:

[image: example_worksheet]

Use the below formula and replace the range `C2:XFD2` with the range of your data. `C2` in my example is the cell where the data begins for the row and `XFD2` is the last cell of the entire sheet:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(C2:XFD2<>""),C2:XFD2)
```

---

In cases where your last revision is in the first column of the sheet, you could specify the the range simply as the entire row:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1<>""),1:1)
```

For the second part of your answer, I cannot help as I have to check the workbook.

Comment: I was also thinking about this initially, but I realized that the main drawback is that it only works when the formula is put in the first column of the sheet (which breaks if you have e.g., an id column in the first column). For completness, an implict assumption in this solution is that the columns of the revisions have the name of the revision itself rather than an "x" or binary 0/1. To address this more explicitly, the formula in row two could look as follows `=LOOKUP(2, 1/(2:2<>""), $1:$1)`. In that way the return value will always be the header rather than the cell itself.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I edited the answer(also formula) so, it can be adjusted accordingly without having to lookup the entire row. Did not use your suggestion as it already covered in your answer if there is a header. I just thought maybe the data in the excel sheet is similar to the screenshot I posted.